# How to keep running timer with service?

Tags: android, service

I have a problem with services i hope you help me.
I have a countdown timer in my activity and i want to keep it running by service.
But when I copy codes the compiler shows NullPointerException.
Please help me. codes are these:

```
public void setMyTimer(){

    countDown.start(86400);
    countDown.setOnCountdownEndListener(new CountdownView.OnCountdownEndListener() {
        @Override
        public void onEnd(CountdownView cv) {

            if (m == 0) {
                a = a + 1000000;
                if (a == 366000000) {
                    a = 0;
                    Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(coordinator, "Game is over", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
                    snackbar.show();
                    cv.stop();
                } else {
                    m = m + a;
                    money.setText(String.valueOf(m));
                    cv.start(86400000);
                }

            } else {
                Snackbar snack = Snackbar.make(coordinator, "You ddin't spend money", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
                snack.show();
            }

        }
    });

}
```

and My service class's codes are:

```
public class TimerService extends Service {

private MainActivity mainActivity = new MainActivity();


@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {

    return null;
}


@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {


    mainActivity.setMyTimer();

    return START_STICKY;
}
```

}

If my codes ruins you i am so sorry because i am a beginner yet.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot create an `Activity` via a call to `new`, they are managed by the framework based on `Intents`.  Same thing with `Service`.  They are also separate components and should not contain direct references to the other.

I'd suggest walking through a course on basic Android development and Java in order to help get past issues like this and get more familiar with the framework.